Whats the earliest source for kiddush bimakom seuda for yom tov?
Most reisonim say the source of kiddush bimakom seuda is Vikasa Shabbos Oneg in the place you call out the shabbos you should have oneg (the meal).
You could say Yom tov is called shabbos and theres a mitzva of oneg( acc to most)
Many poskim assume theres kiddush bimakom seuda by yom tov as well.
But do any reishonim discuss kiddush bimakom seuda by yom tov?

Kiddush bimakom seuda is only Derabanan so Vikrasa L'Shabbos Oneg is only an asmachta. Kiddush on Yom Tov is also Derabanon but they gave it the same halachos of Kiddush on Shabbos (see mishna brura 271:2)

@Schmerel though ive seen acc to rabbi akiva eiger that woman arent chayiv in oneg they wouldnt need kiddush bimakom seuda. And rav shlomo asks on noda biyihuda that holds theres no mitzva of oneg yom tov, u wouldnt need kiddush bimakom seuda
